# invalid syntax error python3

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.x

can someone please explain this error message to me please

```
File "game.py", line 3, in <module>
  import random
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/random.py", line 40, in <module>
  from types import MethodType as _MethodType, BuiltinMethodType as _BuiltinMethodType
File "/home/twitches/Documents/types.py", line 6
  print x
```

I used () with my print in line 6

```
print("Hello")
```

Answer (score 3):

The traceback is pretty clear. You have a file, with the same name, as standard Python module -
[`types`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html). Rename/move your file `/home/twitches/Documents/types.py`

Comment: It's a different problem, but it doesn't seem to explain the syntax error with `print`.

Comment: @chepner, Perhaps, code in `/home/twitches/Documents/types.py` is written for Python 2.x, this way this line throws an error. Is it what you're asking about?

Comment: The OP has already said he used parentheses in his `type.py`, but the error is showing a parentheses-less call. There might be a mismatch here, where the file being imported is not the one the OP thinks is.

Comment: @chepner, The OP doesn't said, that he used parentheses in __type.py__. He just said: `I used () with my print in line 6` - it may be another file, since given _line 6_ by the OP `print("Hello")` is differs from _line 6_ from traceback. I think, he doesn't understand, which file threw the error.

Comment: Good point: `x` vs "hello"

Comment: chepner you are absolutely correct, thank you so much. I had a file names types.py in the same directory, as soon as I changed the filename it worked fine.I put in the part about using () because in reasearching this error found in python3 you need () with print. I could not figure out what the traceback meant , I am barely past hello world at this point. thanks again!